# Encode value forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am validating my model to accept accents and ñ, but passing through the form the character is not coded and admin shows that it is not a valid character. example

I put this in the admin: **administración** and this takes the forms.py

```
<input name="nombre" value="administraciÃ³n" class="vTextField" maxlength="100" type="text" id="id_nombre" />
```

The code is this:

**Models.py**

```
class CapituloSerie(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField("Capitulo",max_length=100,unique=True)
    url_seo = models.SlugField(max_length=250, blank=True, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.nombre+'-'+ format(self.temporada)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.url_seo = defaultfilters.slugify(self.nombre)
        super(CapituloSerie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

import hashlib
EXPRE = r'^[A-Za-záéíóúñÑ \d():-]+$'


class CapituloForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CapituloSerie

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        super(CapituloForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        titulo_field = self.fields['nombre']
        print "Formulario"
        print self['nombre']

        self.fields['nombre'] = forms.RegexField(EXPRE, label=titulo_field.label, max_length=titulo_field.max_length)
```

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from jalvarez.series import models
from jalvarez.series.form import CapituloForm

class CapituloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude=('visitas',)
    print "Admin"   
    form = CapituloForm

admin.site.register(models.CapituloSerie,CapituloAdmin)
```

All my files have this # - coding: utf-8 - at first. Any idea to encode the value in the forms.py ?.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `__unicode__` method as it does not return a unicode string:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre+'-'+ format(self.temporada)
```

I don't know what is `self.temporada` and how do you plan to format the string, but try something in the lines of:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'{0} - {1}'.format(self.nombre, self.temporada)
```

Similarly, your regex should look like

```
EXPRE = ur'^[A-Za-záéíóúñÑ \d():-]+$'
```

Comment: Very good characters are encoded  `<input name="nombre" value="administración" class="vTextField" maxlength="100" type="text" id="id_nombre" />`, but the admin show **Enter a valid value.**. why?.  self.temporada is to show in admin _The vyper and mountain - Season 4_